# tesseract (.NET) + searchable PDF. How to apply?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I have the need to develop a system that turns an image into a searchable PDF.
How is a school work i need something with open source
After much research I found tessnet2 (tesseract) and I can remove a text the image in tiff format.
But how to convert this information into a PDF?
Attention : I need to keep the file structure.

I need a direction to proceed with my research. Someone help me please.

thank you

Comment: I guess to be able to do this you would need an OCR library that would do the job for you. It is a little too complicated to be able to discuss on QnA site.

Comment: Shakti What do you suggest me?

Comment: I suggest using: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C) just like I do myself for this type of work. Code can be learned to recognize new contour from both scans as Fonts. I use it myself for license plate detection.

Comment: user2754599 - As I understand it would help me to detect the text, great! But how to convert to searchable pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of .NET hOCR-to-PDF libraries that you may want to check out at Tesseract [3rdParty](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/User-Projects-%E2%80%93-3rdParty) page.

Comment: Already being very useful, have any examples of how to apply on windows?

Comment: [hOcr2Pdf.NET](http://hocrtopdf.codeplex.com/documentation) site has some code example. You can use [Tesseract 3.x .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) to output hOCR strings to be used as input to the library.